# How to set elements from a json file into a React component

Tags: reactjs, json, select, components

I have tried to create a select component for my website with react, it works fine when you write it but when using data from a json file, you can see all the choices, but when you click on one, it is not chosen.
You can find my code below :

```
function BasicSelect(props) {
    let AllItems = () => props.category.items.map((item) => <MenuItem value={item}>{item}</MenuItem>)

    const [item, setItem] = React.useState('');

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setItem(event.target.value);
    };

    return (
        <Box sx={{ minWidth: 130 }}>
            <FormControl fullWidth>
                <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">{props.category.name}</InputLabel>
                <Select
                    labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                    id="demo-simple-select"
                    value={item}
                    label={"Item"}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    onClick={handleChange}
                >
                <AllItems/>
                </Select>
            </FormControl>
        </Box>
    );
}
```

And here is my JSON file :

```
{
    "name" : "background",
    "items" : ["red", "orange", "yellow" , "green" , "cyan" ,"blue" , "avax" , "beach", "winter" , "summer" , "desert", "forest"]
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the <Select /> element from? A library, or is it also custom?

Answer (score 0):

We are using `AllItems` in a wrong way.
In this case, `AllItems` is a component itself, so `Select` component won't receive `Change` event, when user clicks on `MenuItem` rendered inside `AllItems` component.

The way to fix this is to make `AllItems` a function, not a component.
Consider the following snippet below.

```
  const renderAllItems = () =>
    props.category.items.map((item, index) => (
      <MenuItem value={item} key={`${props.category}-${index}`}>
        {item}
      </MenuItem>
    ));

...

        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={item}
          label={"Item"}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          {renderAllItems()}
        </Select>
```

Here you can find full working example. https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-shockley-lwhl8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yes now it works thank you !!